# Proper Example For jsPDF (Convert html/doc to pdf by javascript or php languages)

Tags: javascript, php, html, docx, jspdf

Is there any proper example for creating pdf by jsPdf for mixed types of:
1- an A4 html page that contains Persian/Arabic text (font)
2- that page is in rtl direction
3- that page contains picture
4- that page contains a table with dotted blue borderd that might extend to more than one page (half of table in one page and other parts in another page)

Thanks for your help.

I want to convert a MS-Doc that is saved as htm to pdf by jsPdf, but mixture of steps above do not have a proper output.

If there is another way to convert the doc/docx/html page to pdf by php or js (client side or server side) that outputs like saving doc as pdf in MS-Word, I gladly want to know that.

Comment: well I remember needing  library to create PDF files, and I specifically remember using pdfkit over jsPDF. maybe that'll get you to what you want.
[pdfkit docs](https://pdfkit.org/index.html)

Comment: I can code it for you if you're having issues with the code part. I need specific details to do that, though.

Comment: Thanks @KJ , but how to convert docx to Images by code?!

Comment: @KJ, but the output of Open Office or Libre Office is not the same as MS-Office. Sometime has significant differences. Till now I can manipulate MS-Word by code. Next step is to transform it to a type that is not editable by user and the user won't need to use any font to see the doc the same as I see (i.e. sth like pdf or image). I got stuck in this step

Comment: @KJ, Thanks a lot, I think I should consider a way to connect a ms server to convert the best way as it could be.